# Override internal stylesheet with external stylesheet, without editing html

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I use Joomla 2.5 and I'd like to override the features of a module which's CSS is actually embedded within the  tag of the html pages the module is on. So in essence, it uses an internal style sheet. I'd like to override that stylesheet without editing the html, as I cannot edit the html pages because these are produced through joomla.

However, I can edit Joomla's external template stylesheet to add style. So my question is, how do I orveride the internal stylesheet with the external stylesheet.

is this possible?

Just produce an example please and I will fill in the blanks myself as I am well knoweldged in CSS and html.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to post some of the HTML? You should be able to override the styles using the ID of an element higher up the HTML node tree. p.s. don't use `!important` unless you absolutely must!

Comment: !important is working, what is the drawbacks of using that?

Comment: I've looked at the html, I really ccan't override it higher up the html node tree. It's a border, whcih's color needs to be overridden.

Comment: If there is no other way, then the only way is `!important`. Personally I would never use it though and have never had to use it as always found a better way. It is down to personal preference at the end of the day.

Comment: Just an example of how to override internal styles. http://jsfiddle.net/zgLkb/ incase you can work with it. You can override anything from using parent id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the CSS `!important` construct to override internal stylesheets.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZKW9/) for an example:

```
<p style="color: red;"> this is a test</p>
```

Will be displayed using a different color if you specify CSS as

```
p {color: #00ff00 !important;}
```

Comment: It's a pain to debug. You may be writing CSS elsewhere and embedding it directly in your HTML and it just 'aint working! Lo & behold, an `!important` tag lurks somewhere in CSS that you did not know about.